# Finite extensions of residue fields of Henselian DVRs

Tags: fields, class-field-theory, valuation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be an Henselian discrete valuation field such that its completion is separable over $K$. Let $F$ be its infinite residue field. Is it true that a finite extension of $F$ is a simple extension i.e., it is of the form $F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$?

Comment: A finite extension of any field is simple, by the primitive element theorem.

Comment: @Sawin: It is true only for finite separable extensions.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but what if you start with an extension $L/F$ which is not simple and then take $K=F((t))$?

Comment: @WillSawin Supplementing the comment of Jana, a finite purely inseparable extension $K/k$ is nontrivially simple if and only if the cotangent complex $L_{K/k}$ has the property that the dimensions of $\pi_i$ are one for $i=0,1$. A proof could be found in Brantner–Waldron.

Answer (score 0):

No, let $F$ be any field and consider $K:=F(\!(x)\!)$ the quotient field of formal power series in $x$ with coefficients in $F$ with the order valuation. Then $K$ is a complete DVR and in particular Henselian. As $K$ is complete it is in particular separable over it self. Now when $F$ is chosen wisely, there are finite (not separable) extensions $L/F$ which are not primitive.

Comment: Your $F$ and $K$ are playing opposite roles than $F$ and $K$ in the OP, where $F$ is the residue field of the complete field $K$.

Comment: I edited, switching $F,K$ to fit with OP's post. (But I'm confused by "$K$ is a DVR", since $K$ is a field, this is probably not the intended statement.)